# Run a function and store it's calculated value and the input value in new data frame

Tags: r

I need to run a function which will perform calculation using certain value store the calculated value in new data frame and the value which is use to perform that calculation.

```
mar <- seq(18,40, by = 1)
ma <- 1+mar
```

The output should be a data frame

```
dataframe
mar   ma
18    19
19    20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```r
original_dataframe <- data.frame(mar = 18:40)

new_dataframe <- within(data = original_dataframe,
                        expr =
                          {
                            ma <- (1 + mar)
                          })

new_dataframe
#>    mar ma
#> 1   18 19
#> 2   19 20
#> 3   20 21
#> 4   21 22
#> 5   22 23
#> 6   23 24
#> 7   24 25
#> 8   25 26
#> 9   26 27
#> 10  27 28
#> 11  28 29
#> 12  29 30
#> 13  30 31
#> 14  31 32
#> 15  32 33
#> 16  33 34
#> 17  34 35
#> 18  35 36
#> 19  36 37
#> 20  37 38
#> 21  38 39
#> 22  39 40
#> 23  40 41
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you want to use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

original_dataframe <- data.frame(mar = 18:40)

new_dataframe <- original_dataframe %>% mutate(ma = (1 + mar))

new_dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

The function could be designed in a number of ways or possibly you could do without a function at all.  Here are some alternatives.

**1)** Create a function with argument `mar` and then set the two columns using it:

```
myfun <- function(mar) data.frame(ma = 1 + mar, mar)

# test
mar <- 18:40
myfun(mar)
```

giving:

```
   ma mar
1  19  18
2  20  19
...etc...
```

**2)** or perhaps you want to pass the bounds for `mar`:

```
myfun2 <- function(lower, upper) {
  stopifnot(lower <= upper)
  mar <- seq(lower, upper)
  data.frame(ma = 1 + mar, mar)
}

# test
myfun2(18, 40)
```

**3)** or we could create a function which accepts either signature:

```
myfun3 <- function(...) {
  stopifnot(..length() == 1 || (..length() == 2 && ..1 <= ..2)
  mar <- if (...length() == 1) ..1 else seq(..1, ..2)
  data.frame(ma = 1 + mar, mar)
}

# test
myfun3(18, 40)
myfun3(18:40)
```

**4)** or if you don't need to create a function at all then it could be done directly:

```
mar <- 18:40
data.frame(ma = 1 + mar, mar)
```